# Using click, how can I display specific options when a choice is selected?

Tags: click

Require and show options only if a choice have been selected using click

When using [click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/)  I want to define different options for specific choice. How can I show different options to a selected choice?
I do have the following piece of code:

```
@cli.command()
@click.option(
    "--method",
    type=click.Choice(
        ["container", "pod", "VM"],
        case_sensitive=False,
    ),

)
@click.option("--name", required=True, type=str, help="Enter container, pod or VM name")
@click.option("--user", required=True, type=str, help="Enter your username")
@click.option("--pass", required=True, type=str, help="Enter your password")
@click.option("--containerpath", required=False, type=str)
@click.option("--podpath", required=False, type=str)
@click.option("--VMpath", required=False, type=str)

@click.pass_context
def launch_option(name, user, pass, containerpath, podpath, VMpath):
    "REST of the CODE"
```

Is there any way to only show the option podpath when I choose the choice pod?